# How to open a fragment from another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having trouble going from one fragment to another.  I've been using the FragmentTransaction.replace() along with the FragmentManager object, but for some reason the app doesn't go to the next fragment.  I'm trying to go from the HomeFragment to the ToDoListFragment through click events in a list view.

HomeFragment.java:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    ArrayList<ToDoList> arrayList;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ToDoList toDoList;

        final Cursor list_result = myDb.getAllListData();


        listView = root.findViewById(R.id.toDoList_list);
        viewData();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
            {
                String text = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                ToDoListFragment fragment = new ToDoListFragment();
                while (list_result.moveToNext())
                {
                    String title = list_result.getString(1);

                    if (title.equals(text))
                    {
                        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.home_container, fragment);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return root;
    }
```

fragment_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toDoList_list"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

ToDoListFragment.java:

```
public class ToDoListFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;

    public ToDoListFragment()
    {

    }

    private ToDoListViewModel mViewModel;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_list_fragment, container, false);
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.task_list);

        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        return view;
    }
```

to_do_list_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/task_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.ToDoListFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/task_list"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    Menu menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        menu = navigationView.getMenu();

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_add_new_list, R.id.nav_delete_list)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also, in transaction.replace() am I suppose to use the id of the FrameLayout from the initial fragment or the fragment I want to go to?

Comment: i posted a code, check it please. You have error because you fragment layout must be in a actyivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is simple, you have a framelayout in a fragment, it is not correct, because the fragment must be contained in a activity

XML Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

In the fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new MyListFragment())
                    .commit();
```

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason the app is still crashing.  I forgot to say that I'm using a Navigation View in the MainActivity so I think that may complicate things a little.  I updated the code with the MainActivity code as well as its layout.  Also, the getSupportFragmentManager() only works with Activities so I'm using getChildFragmentManager() within the HomeFragment instead.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though because I didn't know the fragment had to be contained within an activity for this to work.